# cannot deploy ReactJS app to github pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, github, github-pages

Hey I have literally been trying this for days, I have went over documentation all over, I followed tutorials and I cannot get past npm run deploy when trying to deploy my react app to github pages. I call npm run build, I place the correct url to package.json as the 'homepage', i call it again and get the 'deploy' and 'predeploy', I definitely have gh-pages in node modules, I mean I got it all I have followed every step that every tutorial could have told me. I have ran into an issue that reads the following:

> error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory fatal: unable to
>   fork
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR!
>   carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build` npm ERR!
>   Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0 deploy script. npm ERR! This is
>   probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-10-04T19_57_57_731Z-debug.log

Here are the contents of the log:

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'deploy' ]
2 info using npm@6.2.0
3 info using node@v10.8.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predeploy', 'deploy', 'postdeploy' ]
5 info lifecycle carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0~predeploy: carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0
6 verbose lifecycle carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0~predeploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0~predeploy: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Carlos\ReactJSProjects\carlos_valencia_portfolio\node_modules.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
8 verbose lifecycle carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0~predeploy: CWD: C:\Users\Carlos\ReactJSProjects\carlos_valencia_portfolio
9 silly lifecycle carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0~predeploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run build' ]
10 silly lifecycle carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0~predeploy: Returned: code: 0  signal: null
11 info lifecycle carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0~deploy: carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0
12 verbose lifecycle carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0~deploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
13 verbose lifecycle carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0~deploy: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Carlos\ReactJSProjects\carlos_valencia_portfolio\node_modules.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
14 verbose lifecycle carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0~deploy: CWD: C:\Users\Carlos\ReactJSProjects\carlos_valencia_portfolio
15 silly lifecycle carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0~deploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'gh-pages -d build' ]
16 silly lifecycle carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0~deploy: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
17 info lifecycle carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0~deploy: Failed to exec deploy script
18 verbose stack Error: carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
18 verbose stack Exit status 1
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:304:16)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:249:5)
19 verbose pkgid carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0
20 verbose cwd C:\Users\Carlos\ReactJSProjects\carlos_valencia_portfolio
21 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
22 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "deploy"
23 verbose node v10.8.0
24 verbose npm  v6.2.0
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno 1
27 error carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
27 error Exit status 1
28 error Failed at the carlos_valencia_portfolio@0.1.0 deploy script.
28 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
29 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

I have no idea what is going on, I read things online saying that I am not pointing at the folder that contains my sh.exe and that I have to specify it in my environment variables and whatnot. I literally tried everything I found in both google, bing and reddit. Im literally stumped and want to cry lol. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to see your `package.json` values for `homepage`, and in the `scripts` object, the `predeploy` and `deploy` values. That being said, here is how to deploy a React app to Github Pages:

- After building your app and pushing to your github repo, install `gh-pages` by running the following in terminal:

  - `npm install --save gh-pages`
- Update your `package.json` with the following:

  - `"homepage": "https://[github-username].github.io/[repo-name]"`
- Inside your `scripts` object:

  - `"predeploy": "npm run build",`
  - `"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"`
- Run

  - `npm run deploy`

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful if you could add some code but might be worth checking out the bottom reply on this post:

https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Pages/My-react-project-doesn-t-work-on-github-pages/m-p/6806#M452

In particular, this section on client-side routing (if applicable to your application):

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#notes-on-client-side-routing

Comment: thanks for your reply, will def take a crack at this once again following this documentation...dumb question and i apologize for it but what code would you want to see??? maybe package.json?

Comment: yea those links really aren't addressing my problem at all, its just repeating the same steps that i have been trying for a while now